# What is the [american] option under Extbook?

Tags: lyx, class-options, extsizes

I noticed that my upgraded Lyx installation adds the following line to the book class using the extsizes package:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,oneside,american]{extbook}
```

I looked at the package documentation but I cannot find a reference to the "american" switch. What does this do?

Secondly, is there a way to edit the provided Lyx templates? Though I have set the default language to "English-USA" compiling throws an error that the Spanish language option under Babel hasn't been loaded. I can fix this is a tex editor, but I'd like to be able to edit the template. I've looked through all the document settings (including Latex preamble to see if it was there) as well as the language settings but I can't find what's causing this error.

Comment: It is an option that will be passed to the packages you load after it (e.g. `babel`)

Comment: The [american]option will be loaded after the babel package? Even though it is a switch in the document class? What function does it perform?

Comment: The `american` option will be *taken* by `babel`, to load american hyphenation patterns and more.

Comment: I would have thought that package options should be loaded when calling the particular package and not in the document class. So "american" is a document class switch that loads U.S. English hyphenation patterns (more what??) in the babel package. Strange.

Comment: It may seem strange, but all the options given to the document class are inherited by the packages you load (provided that they accept such an option).

Comment: So what happens if I load a different language as a {babel} package switch? There will be a conflict. In Lyx, the [american] switch is loaded without any user input upon selecting the extbook document class. So the second part of my question was, how to edit these provided Lyx templates?

Comment: I'm not familiar with Lyx at all.

Comment: About your bounty text: this is precisely why we like to keep a single question per "question": not everyone will be able to provide a satisfactory answer (in their mind) to all parts of a multi-part question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

LyX adds the "american" option so that it will be passed to babel. To get around this, we just need to tell LyX "don't worry about babel, I will do it myself". There are two ways to do this:

### Way 1

Go to Document > Settings > Language and for "Language package" select "None".

### Way 2

Go to Document > Settings > Local Layout and enter the following:

```
Provides babel 1
```

Then press "Validate" and then "OK".

LyX no longer loads babel and thus no longer needs to pass a language through the class options. You must now manually load babel with the appropriate options.

Comment: What's the reason for passing `american` by default? Or loading `babel` by default, either.

Comment: @egreg the default is detected by LyX (perhaps based on the local or GUI language). For me it comes up as "english". The language can always be changed by going to Document > Settings > Language. As for why loading babel by default, I don't know.

Comment: One of the reasons why I don't like LyX: I don't want that *they* decide what's best for me. `;-)`

Comment: @egreg yes, I can understand that. It's all about choosing what you want to delegate. Most LyX users like delegating a lot to LyX.

Answer (score 3):

1. Is there any reason for loading `extbook`? No, except doing typesetting for children books or visually impaired people.
2. Why does LyX add the `american` option when `extbook` is requested? I don't know and I see no sensible reason.
3. Is there an `american` option for `extbook`? No. But all options passed to the class are examined; they do nothing if they are not defined by the class, but *they are passed to all subsequently loaded package*. They are known as *global options*.
4. Will you have a problem if you specify a different language, say `\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}`? Yes, definitely, because the global options are evaluated *after* the local option *ngerman*, so the default language will be `american`. If you have a fairly recent TeX distribution, you can solve the issue by doing

   ```
   \usepackage[main=ngerman]{babel}
   ```

   You can also pass other languages (without `main=`, of course).
5. How to do this in LyX? Sorry, I don't know. It's a question for a specific LyX forum.

Answer (score 0):

It is a so-called "global option" that will be passed to any package you load with a \usepackage command, most notably to the babel package.